# Symbol used to indicate indivisibility

Tags: symbols

In the following definition, I am denoting the condition that $a$ is not an integral multiple of $b$. Why is there such a big space between $b$ and the vertical bar with a slash through it?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent
The integers $q$ and $r$ are called the \textbf{quotient} and \textbf{remainder}, 
respectively, in the division of $a$ by $b$. If $r \neq 0$, $a$ is not divisible by $b$. 
The indivisibility of $a$ by $b$ is denoted by \boldmath$b \not\vert a$\unboldmath.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{amssymb}` and `\nmid`

Comment: If, for some reason, you can't use `\nmid`, I suggest you write `$b\mathrel{\not\vert}a$` to get even spacing around `\not\vert`. That said, `\nmid` looks a lot better...

Comment: What is the code to indicate that $a$ is divisible by $b$?

Comment: $b \vert a$, or $b \mid a$?

Comment: $b\mid a$ has the correct spacing.

Comment: For future reference, [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) can be used to find many symbols, including `\nmid`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spacing issue is caused by the fact that there are three different kinds of math symbols: binary operations (e.g. `+` and `\times`, binary relations (e.g. `<` and `\leq`) and ordinary characters (e.g. `!` and `\infty`). Each has its own spacing. Relations typically have the largest, slightly more than operations and significantly more than ordinary characters. Operation spacing uses `\mathbin`, relation spacing uses `mathrel`, and ordinary character spacing can use `{}` (or nothing if it's already an ordinary character). These are illustrated in the following table:

[image]

Since "divides" is a relation, the correct spacing is given by `\mathrel`, which is the default for `\mid`. The negated relation, as suggested in the comments by @egreg is given by the command `\nmid`. Notice that the spacing is identical to `\mid`.

`\nmid` uses the `amssymb` package.

Here is the code to produce the above table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
$a\vert b$ & \verb`$a\vert b$`\\
$a|b$ & \verb`$a|b$`\\
$a\mathbin{|}b$ & \verb`$a\mathbin{|}b$`\\
$a\mathrel{|}b$ & \verb`$a\mathrel{|}b$`\\
$a\mid b$ & \verb`$a\mid b$`\\
$a\nmid b$ & \verb`$a\nmid b$`
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```